# How to test in Junit 4.12 PSQLException with annotation @Test(expected = PSQLException.class)

Tags: java, postgresql, junit

I expected `PSQLException` in test:

```
@Test(expected = org.postgresql.util.PSQLException.class)
public void whenAdditionInProposalWhereAuthorNotExistThen() {

    final Proposal proposal = new Proposal();
    proposal.setUrlRecruiter("url_recruiter");
    proposal.setUlrPropose("url_propose");
    proposal.setHeader("header");
    proposal.setAuthor("author_which_not_exist_in_recruiter_table");
    proposal.setCreate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));


    final InjectorInProposal injector = new InjectorInProposal(properties, connection);

    //Testing ingection.

    injector.injectInProposal(proposal); //(line 115)this throw PSQLException

}
```

Method:

```
public void injectInProposal(final Proposal proposal) {

    try (final PreparedStatement statement =

                 connection.prepareStatement(

                         properties.getValue("add_to_proposal"))
    ) {


        statement.setString(1, proposal.getHeader());

        statement.setString(4, proposal.getNickname());

        statement.setString(2, proposal.getUlrPropose());

        statement.setTimestamp(3, proposal.getCreateTime());


        statement.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My test fail but my StackTrace show me:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "proposal" violates foreign key constraint "proposal_nickname_fkey"
  Подробности: Key (nickname)=(author_which_not_exist_in_recruiter_table) is not present in table "recruiter".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at ru.pravvich.jdbc.action.InjectorInProposal.injectInProposal(InjectorInProposal.java:48)
    at ru.pravvich.jdbc.action.InjectorInProposalTest.whenAdditionInProposalWhereAuthorNotExistThen(InjectorInProposalTest.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
```

Whats wrong? I have `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or...` in first line my StackTrace and same time `java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` in last line in StackTrace.

Why? How I can do it? I'm not use ORM system, only clean JDBC driver.

Comment: It seems like the `injectInProposal` is not throwing the Exception, just catching it and logging. Have you checked it?

Comment: @BrunoDM I'm wrote `try (PSQLException e) { injector.injectInProposal(proposal); } catch { e.printStackTrace(); }` but this did't compiling. I'm sure  what `injector.injectInProposal(proposal)` throwing exception because StackTrace log Indicates on line which contain  `injector.injectInProposal(proposal)`.

Comment: Please,post here this injectInProposal method

Comment: @BrunoDM I'm added method in question.

Comment: You caught and swallowed the exception in `injectInProposal`, so the test won't see it.

Comment: @BrunoDM yes you right! I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer...sorry for the bad format..smartphone

Comment: @BrunoDM It's smartphone style))) You are great! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
public void injectInProposal(final Proposal proposal) { try (final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement( properties.getValue("add_to_proposal")) ) { statement.setString(1, proposal.getHeader()); statement.setString(4, proposal.getNickname()); statement.setString(2, proposal.getUlrPropose()); statement.setTimestamp(3, proposal.getCreateTime()); statement.executeUpdate(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
```

You should not try catch this method. You are taking the Exception and just logging it. Change the method to log (or not) and rethrow the Exception. Remember, this will change the methods signature, where now it will throw the Exception.

Example:

```
public void injectInProposal(final Proposal proposal) throws SQLException { try (final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement( properties.getValue("add_to_proposal")) ) { statement.setString(1, proposal.getHeader()); statement.setString(4, proposal.getNickname()); statement.setString(2, proposal.getUlrPropose()); statement.setTimestamp(3, proposal.getCreateTime()); statement.executeUpdate(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace();
```

throw e; } }

You maybe should change the @Test.expected class as well